# How to print Metadata of a file with the help of command-line?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, file-metadata, trisquel

I am using [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info) 7.0 with Nautilus 3.10.1 installed.

Whenever I display properties of a file, I've one file-specific tab like: Image,Audio/Video,Document etc. which displays special information about it.

Example for a Image:

[image: screenshot]

Example for a PDF Document:

[image: screen-shot]

How does Nautilus get this type of file-specific information?

And **how do I print this information (MetaData) with te command-line**?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the first level of information in the command line, you can use `file`.

```
$ file gtu.pdf 
gtu.pdf: PDF document, version 1.4
```

For most formats, and more detailed information, you can also use
[**Exiftool**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool):

```
NAME
       exiftool - Read and write meta information in files

SYNOPSIS
       exiftool [OPTIONS] [-TAG...] [--TAG...] FILE...
       exiftool [OPTIONS] -TAG[+-<]=[VALUE]... FILE...
       exiftool [OPTIONS] -tagsFromFile SRCFILE [-SRCTAG[>DSTTAG]...] FILE...
       exiftool [ -ver | -list[w|f|r|wf|g[NUM]|d|x] ]

       For specific examples, see the EXAMPLES sections below.

       This documentation is displayed if exiftool is run without an input FILE when one is expected.

DESCRIPTION
       A command-line interface to Image::ExifTool, used for reading and writing meta information in a variety of
       file types.  FILE is one or more source file names, directory names, or "-" for the standard input.
       Information is read from source files and printed in readable form to the console (or written to output text
       files with -w).
```

Example:

```
$ exiftool IMG_20151104_102543.jpg 
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.46
File Name                       : IMG_20151104_102543.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2.8 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:11:04 10:25:44+05:30
File Access Date/Time           : 2015:11:17 18:56:49+05:30
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2015:11:11 14:55:43+05:30
File Permissions                : rwxrwxrwx
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
GPS Img Direction               : 0
GPS Date Stamp                  : 2015:11:04
GPS Img Direction Ref           : Magnetic North
GPS Time Stamp                  : 04:55:43
Camera Model Name               : Micromax A121
Aperture Value                  : 2.1
Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Interoperability Version        : 0100
Create Date                     : 2002:12:08 12:00:00
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/808
Color Space                     : sRGB
Date/Time Original              : 2015:11:04 10:25:44
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Exif Image Height               : 2400
Exif Version                    : 0220
Exif Image Width                : 3200
Focal Length                    : 3.5 mm
Flash                           : Auto, Did not fire
Exposure Time                   : 1/809
ISO                             : 100
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
X Resolution                    : 72
Make                            : Micromax
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail Offset                : 640
Thumbnail Length                : 12029
Image Width                     : 3200
Image Height                    : 2400
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Aperture                        : 2.1
GPS Date/Time                   : 2015:11:04 04:55:43Z
Image Size                      : 3200x2400
Shutter Speed                   : 1/809
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 12029 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Focal Length                    : 3.5 mm
Light Value                     : 11.9
```

There are also specific commands for some type of files, like **pdf**:

```
$ pdfinfo gtu.pdf 
Title:          Microsoft Word - Thermax Ltd
Author:         User
Creator:        PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 8.15
CreationDate:   Tue Jan 27 11:51:38 2015
ModDate:        Tue Jan 27 12:30:40 2015
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot:       0
File size:      64209 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.4
```

Answer (score 5):

The actual meaning of generic "file metadata" would involve whatever information **is not stored** inside the file itself which is the **data**. It's [data about the data](http://data%20about%20the%20data).

Under such a meaning, metadata include (but are not limited to):

- Access rights
- Size in bytes and in blocks
- SELinux security context string
- User and Group ID of the owner
- Time of last modification

This type of information is normally stored into the filesystem and not into the file itself.

Now, as far as Linux (and Unix-like) CLI is concerned, there is a small nifty tool called `stat` which can provide all available metadata for a file, a file system or any other file system-related item (like directories, devices and named pipes).

It uses a `printf`-like notation to define the actual information to be printed out, or a default selection when such an option is not used.

This is an example run:

```
[enzo@Feynman ~] stat /etc/hosts 
  File: /etc/hosts
  Size: 139             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10303h/66307d   Inode: 268684872   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2021-09-14 18:00:17.200000397 +0200
Modify: 2021-09-14 17:59:37.506668910 +0200
Change: 2021-09-14 17:59:37.520002245 +0200
 Birth: 2021-09-14 17:59:37.506668910 +0200
```

The earlier answer shows a mix of file metadata and data extracted with a specific tool for each file type, so it is not strictly about metadata.

On the other hand, `stat` is more generic and works on any file object and doesn't access the file data itself.

For extra details about the actual content type, thus not really *metadata* in the strict sense, you can make use of the ubiquitous [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) tool which uses a large "*signature*" database (the *magic numbers database*) to guess the file content, no matter what its name can be: it doesn't use the so-called file name extension.